# Can't construct object because member doesn't have default constructor

Tags: c++, initialization

When compiling my program, I am getting this error:

```
error: constructor for 'parser' must explicitly initialize the member 'lexer_inst' which does not have a default constructor
```

As the error mentions, my member "lexer_inst" doesn't have a default constructor. However, I don't want it to be default-constructed in the first place. I am writing to the member in the constructor anyway. It seems illogical to me that I wouldn't be able to keep the member uninitialized until I initialize it myself. In my case, I can't use the initializer list for my member because it depends on the value of another member that is being created in the constructor.

This is my constructor code:

```cpp
parser::parser(source_file &file) : file(file) {
    this->ast_arena = arena(file.data.length * 4);
    this->lexer_inst = lexer(this->ast_arena, file);
}
```

How can I keep "lexer_inst" uninitialized? (It has the type "lexer", which actually has reference members and therefore can't be default initialized)

Comment: What about using a `std::unique_ptr<lexer>`? Or a `std::shaed_ptr<lexer>` if your class isn't supposed to own thw instance.

Comment: So why doesn't `parser::parser(source_file& file) : file(file), ast_arena(file.data.length*4), lexer_inst(ast_arena, file)` work? I'm assuming that these members are declared in the appropriate order in your class.

Comment: Your request that you be allowed to keep items uninitialised would significantly compromise C++ as a language. The compiler would need to emit code to track uninitialised items, (so that they don't get destructed or copied for instance). If you really need that facility then C++ expects you to do the work yourself. You might want to investigate *placement new* for example (although I don't think you could make that work where references are concerned).

Comment: You can't keep any member of a class uninitialised. Instead, ensure, in class `parser`, that `file`, `ast_arena` and `lexer_inst` members have the same access control (`public`, `private`, etc) and that they are declared in order (`file` before before `ast_arena` before `lexer_inst`).   Then change `parser`s constructor to `parser::parser(source_file &file) : file(file), ast_arena(file.data.length *4), lexer(ast_arena, file) {}`.     Additionally, in interests of readability, don't give an argument of the constructor the same name as a member of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I keep "lexer_inst" uninitialized?

You can’t, and you shouldn’t. Change your constructor to

```
parser::parser(source_file& file)
    : file(file)
    , ast_arena(file.data.length * 4)
    , lexer_inst(ast_arena, file) {}
```

That is, *exclusively* use the member initialiser list to set up your class, don’t attempt to push this initialisation into the constructor’s body.

Make sure that your order of member declaration mirrors the order of the initialisation, otherwise the above will fail. Good compilers will warn you if that’s not the case.

Comment: This is incomplete, as the order of initialisers in the initialiser list doesn't determine the order in which the members are initialised/constructed.    More is needed to ensure that `file` (the member) is constructed before `ast_arena`, and that `ast_arena` is constructed before `lexer_inst`.